Children's novel about dolls with black eyes and black watch faces to mind control children
I remember reading this book when I was a kid, but I pretty much only remember the ending. I read it sometime around 2008-2012, but it could have been published anytime before then. It was probably Children's fiction or YA fiction genre. I believe the protagonist was a young girl. At the end of the book, it is revealed that a company has evil plans (probably to take over the world, but I forget the exact details), which would be brought about by using a kind of black stone material. This material would be made into doll's eyes for girls, and watch faces for boys, and I believe it would have the effect of mind controlling them or something. I think all this was revealed in a epilogue-like, exposition-heavy section at the end.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  Was this a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?

You asked this elsewhere a year ago. Have you remembered any other details since then? https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/10gm5i5/tomtbook2000schildrens_or_ya_book_about_an/ Are there any books you've considered and then ruled out?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what language did you read the story in? What was on the book cover? Where did you get the book from? How young was the protagonist (teen, preteen, younger)? How does making watch faces and doll's eyes allow them to take over the world? What was the protagonist's name? Was the book written by a man or a woman?

This must be The Silver Crown  (Robert C. O'Brien, 1968). I don't have access to the book (I read it in the late 1970s), and Google Books has a limited preview, but there are lots of partial quotes there that confirm doll's eyes and watch faces made out of "malignite", the black stone material that OP cites, e.g.

"[The watch] had black hands and little black dots that marked the minutes. 'Malignite won't make watch gears,' said the King, 'but it works beautifully on the face.'"


"... 'There's no reason why a little malignite shouldn't be used in ... doll with malignite eyes.'"

From a blog post ("malignite" is a much better search term than "Silver Crown"):

This machine can control other people who are “in tune” or hypnotize them into obeying only its commands. The Hieronymus machine obtains its full powers when it is near malignite, a black stuff that is responsible for making the Hieronymus machine be able to control other people.

(emphasis added)

the Wikipedia entry quotes a Kirkus Reviews review that corroborates your memory that the end of the book is exposition-heavy ...
malignite is apparently a real mineral; it seems to actually be black but I'm guessing that the author was using the similarity to "malignant" to make a point ...


Lol how I'm only on Chapter 7-8, so I can't confirm, but maybe add this Cover List so OP can see if any match memories? https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/26206-the-silver-crown
